# How to avoid left outer join when finding by embedded object id in Spring Data JPA

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two entity classes:

```
class One {
    Long id;

    <Other properties>

    @ManyToOne
    Two two;
}

class Two {
    Long id;

    <Other properties>
}
```

Now, in `OneRepository`, I have a method:

```
One findByIdAndTwoId(Long oneId, Long twoId);
```

When this method is called, the query sent to the database is:

```
    select
        <properties>
    from
        one one0_ 
    left outer join
        two two1_ 
            on one0_.two_id=two1_.id 
    where
        and one0_.id=? 
        and two1_.id=?
```

Whereas I expect it to be of the form:

```
    select
        <properties>
    from
        one one0_ 
    where
        and one0_.id=? 
        and one0_.two_id=?
```

Is there any way to get this done? Please help.

**EDIT:**

If I use a criteria query as mentioned below, the resulting query has no join clause.

```
        CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<One> cq = cb.createQuery(One.class);
        Root<One> oneRoot = cq.from(One.class);
        cq.select(oneRoot).where(
                cb.equal(oneRoot.get("id"), oneId),
                cb.equal(oneRoot.get("two").get("id"), twoId)
        );
        TypedQuery<One> query = entityManager.createQuery(cq);
        return query.getSingleResult();
```

Comment: No. But why do you think that the second query is better than the first? Did you check the execution plan?

Comment: I am thinking why to have a join with another table when everything that is required is in a single table.

Comment: Sure but that's how Hibernate works.

Comment: But if I have a method `One findByIdAndTwo(Long oneId, Two two);` then there is no join in the query.

Comment: For `findByIdAndTwo` there no need to join because you are passing child obj but for `findByIdAndTwoId` you are doing query by `TwoId` means `Two` entity's `id` field so it join `Two` entity to use `two.id` in where clause.

Comment: Yes, I know that and that is why I am not asking why `findByIdAndTwoId` results in a join, I am looking for some way to have a query without join while using the id.

Answer (score 0):

Use JPA native query

Using @Query annotation you can execute native queries by setting the nativeQuery flag to true.

```
@Query(value = "select * from one o where o.id=?1 and o.two_id=?2", nativeQuery = true)
One findByIdAndTwoId(Long oneId, Long twoId);
```

Comment: Do not want to use a native query. I like to use a native query only in cases where the desired result cannot be achieved using any other way.

Comment: I don't think any other way using Spring data JPA to do that possible. Please inform me if you find any

Comment: And using native query is not a bad practice at all.

Comment: Not a bad practice, its just that I do not like to use magic stings in my code.